# Problema a importar modulo paramiko

Tags: python

Tengo problema a importar el módulo paramiko en python 3.7.0 en windows 10:

```
>>>import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2018.3.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'
```

Cuando lo instalo me dice esto al final de la instalación:

```
 File "c:\users\angel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 493, in _find_latest_available_vc_ver
raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
 distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp
-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5i8fflz8\cffi
```

Pues ya instalé el Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 con todas sus herramientas satisfactoriamente y pues me encuentro con el siguiente problema cuando intento instalar nuevamente paramiko:

```
 File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hnmwgx81\pynacl\setup.py", line 159, in run
raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
 ----------------------------------------


PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'C:\\Users\\Angel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hnmwgx81\\bcrypt
```

Pues luego de un de una larga búsqueda descargué el módulo directamente de GitHub desde este enlace e instalando las herramientas de Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 pude solucionarlo. Grasias por su Ayuda

https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko

Comment: Para algunas bibliotecas/librerias de python necesitas las herramientas de compilación de Visual C++ si estas usando windows.

Comment: Hay varias formar de obtener las herramientas de compilación yo personalmente installo Visual Studio IDE y el paqueta de c++, pero si no te interesa puedas descargar solo el instalador de las herramientas de compilación usando este link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159)

Comment: Despues de que descargues eh instales el paquete te recomiendo reinicar tu pc, prueba volver a instalar el paquete que quieres y en teoria ya deberia de estar solucionado el problema.

Comment: @AllanGarcia Help

Comment: ¿Si, dime que pasa?